# Understanding the displacement vector

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Let the points $P_1(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $P_2(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ exist on $\mathbb R^3$. I understand the position vector of $P_1$ is $r_1=\left< x_1, y_1, z_1\right>$ and likewise the position vector of $P_2$ is $r_2=\left< x_2, y_2, z_2 \right>$

What I don't understand is why the displacement vector, $\vec{P_1P_2}$, is defined by $r_2-r_1$.

I tried using the parallelogram law and realized it wasn't working. I tried to construct a right triangle intersecting the points $P_1$ and $P_2$ and using the pythagorean theorem, but I realized that didn't make sense.

How do I make sense of this? This feels like a silly question to me but I just can't make sense of it.

Comment: What is your confusion? Is it that you can't understand why it's $r_2-r_1$ instead of $r_1-r_2$? Or is it the fact that the displacement is some vector minus the other one?

Comment: Let $O$ denote the origin. Vector addition would mean $\overrightarrow{OP_1}+\overrightarrow{P_1P_2}=\overrightarrow{OP_2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [displacement vector](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osuniversityphysics/chapter/4-1-displacement-and-velocity-vectors/) $\vec d$ between vectors $\vec{r_1}$ and $\vec{r_2}$ is defined as that vector which added to $\vec{r_1}$ gives $\vec{r_2}$ as result, that is

$$\vec{r_1}+\vec d = \vec{r_2} \iff \vec d = \vec{r_2}-\vec{r_1}$$

[image]